# tensorflow string_split on batch data

Tags: tensorflow

From tensorflow offical doc, it says

> For example: N = 2, source[0] is 'hello world' and source[1] is 'a b c', then the output will be st.indices = [0, 0; 0, 1; 1, 0; 1, 1; 1, 2] st.shape = [2, 3] st.values = ['hello', 'world', 'a', 'b', 'c']

What if I want something like [['hello', 'world'], ['a','b','c']], how can I get this? 

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tf.map_fn` to map your batch onto the function `tf.string_split`.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn

The map function will split your batch along the first dimension (your batch size, `N` as referenced by the documentation in your question), then it will pass each of the samples to `tf.string_split` individually, each of which will return `['hello', 'world']` and `['a', 'b', 'c']` respectively. Then the map function will recombine the individual results into an array which will result in `[['hello', 'world'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]` as desired.

Comment: how can we use `tf.string_split()` for a tensor having shape `[None, None]`?

Comment: are you sure this works? the `map_fn` seems to expect the input and output of the mapper to have the same shape....